# How to make the functions run in a certain sequence in android programming?

Tags: android

I'm a new android programmer, and recently I found some problem when programming.
In the main activity, there are three functions, `a()`, `b()`, `c()`, for example. So what can I do to make sure that `c()` will run after `a()` and `b()` are finished?

Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    a();//get view
    b();//do sth for view like set text in text view

    //trigger.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //@Override
        //public void onClick(View v) {
        //  c();
        //}
    //});
    //this is using a button to call the function, but I want it run automatically after a() and b() finish
}
```

Comment: unless you are doing some threading in a and b they should always run before c in that structure

Comment: Can't you add b(); to the end of a(); and c(); to the end of b();?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it by using runnable. I should make sure that the main thread only deal with the change of control

Answer (score 0):

to be sure, create a new functions B() outside onCreate(). Then call C() at the end of B() and B() at the end of a()...

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a(), b() and c() out of onCreate and call them in the order that you want like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    a();
    b();
    c();
}
private void a(){...}
private void b(){
...
trigger.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      c();
    }
//});
}
private void c(){...}
```

if you have any async tasks then you will have to implementate the onPostExecute() method after every AsyncTask call